# How to access Oauth Response from Square URL redirect

Tags: django, oauth, square-connect, square

I am building a website in Django that utilizes the Square OAuth system. https://developer.squareup.com/docs/oauth-api/overview

I am able to access the link they provide, login to my account, redirect to my website with the access code in the URL link. From here I am at a loss at how to actually access the code that is being provided in my redirect from Square.

How do i access to code being given to me in the url that I receive from the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Since your using Django which is Python based we have an example in [Python](https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/e53267710be871da87e81eef776c2c738498eebb/connect-examples/oauth/python/oauth-flow.py#L54) that you can use.

Comment: Is this specific only to flask? I wrote it in Django

Comment: True, this example does uses flask. Are you getting the callback from the authorization request? In the example it's just a GET request on the callback.